# jQuery ajax convertor. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can create convertor for my own mime type:

```
    $.ajax( url, {
        accepts: { dload: 'application/x-dload' },
        contents: { dload: /dload/ },
        converters: {
            "text dload": jQuery.parseJSON,
        },
        dataType: 'dload',
        success: function( data, status, xhr ){
            ... data is of dload type
        },
    })
```

But is is possible to provide convertors to my mime type when response is not text? for example xml or html?

This does not work:

```
    $.ajax( url, {
        accepts: { dload: 'application/x-dload' },
        contents: { dload: /dload/ },
        converters: {
            "text dload": jQuery.parseJSON,
            "xml dload": convert_xml_to_dload,
            "html dload": convert_html_to_dload,
        },
        dataType: 'dload',
        success: function( data, status, xhr ){
            ... data is of dload type
        },
    })
```

Comment: converter's value should be a function. So try using anonymous function

Comment: @AswinKumar those are functions, or at least `jQuery.parseJSON` certainly is

Comment: @AswinKumar: `convert_xml_to_dload` is function name. There is no difference between anonymous function and named function

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it out, but looking on jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#using-converters You probably need something like this:

```
converters: {
    "text dload": true,
    "dload json": jQuery.parseJSON,
    "dload xml": convert_xml_to_dload, // or jQuery.parseXML
    "dload html": convert_html_to_dload,
}
```

Comment: I saw that section. And it speaks about converting dload to other types